# Reverse Tethering (USB) Android Tablet

Tags: usb, lan, android, tethering

Scenario: Android Tablet (3.2/ICS)   Ubuntu Server

I have a local apache server running on my ubuntu 10 machine - which serves data to my android app. This works fine over wireless internet (connecting to my local ip address) but I need to work without wireless - just with a usb connection.

There are some tutorials out there on 'reverse tethering' which seems to be what I need. My android device is rooted and easily accessible by abd on my ubuntu machine.

Most Android Tablets do not have native tethering settings (which is required by most tutorials out there) So when doing something like ifconfig usb0 up - it does not recognize the interface. Also many of the tutorials are windows specific

My tablets are running 3.2 honeycomb and ICS

Is reverse usb tethering the only way to go about this? Or is there another way - perhaps purely through abd or ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse tethering solved your issue

Here is steps for reverse tethering  [click here](https://gist.github.com/b1cac45178eb33f4e95d)
It required root you're device.